# Xamarin mac 2.10 compatible exif library

Tags: xamarin, exif, xamarin.mac, exiflib

I used https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExifLib.PCL/ library, before update.

I'm not able to use this library now :

> Could not install package 'ExifLib.PCL 1.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any alternative ?

I use Exif library to get image taken date:

```
using (var stream = File.Open (filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
                var ein=new CGImagePropertiesExif ();
                var jpegInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg (stream);
                if (jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal != null) {
                    takenDate = DateTime.ParseExact (jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);
                }
            }
```

this code terminates application , also can't seen any exceptions :(

if I just mock datetime , like this:

```
static DateTime GetMyImageTakenDate (NSUrl url)
        {
            DateTime takenDate = DateTime.Today;

            using (var stream = File.Open (url.Path, FileMode.Open)) {

                takenDate = DateTime.ParseExact (DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);
            }
            return takenDate;
        }
```

application works fine :/

Comment: Try the pre-release version: `ExifLib.PCL 1.0.2-pre01` It has been updated to support  .netstandard 1.0

Comment: thaaanks :)) it works .

Comment: but i still have a problem,  I use exif lib to get image taken date
var jpegInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg (stream);
    if (jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal != null) {
     takenDate = DateTime.ParseExact (jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);
    }

it terminates application :(

Comment: Can't you read exif data from a PHAsset directly?\

Comment: I haven't tried, if you can ,please link me any example.

Comment: @Nininea What line of code is it terminating on? See my answer, working fine for me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me:

```
var filePath = "/Users/sushi/Desktop/img_1771.jpg";
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var jpegInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(stream);
    if (jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal != null)
    {
        var takenDate = DateTime.ParseExact(jpegInfo.DateTimeOriginal, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);
        Console.WriteLine(takenDate);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12/14/2003 12:01:44 PM
```

Using:

```
Xamarin.Mac Version: 2.10.0.105
ExifLib.PCL Version: 1.0.2-pre01
```

Comment: this code is use inside modal. here is main process, I should get taken date while uploading info and also should copy image inside my directory, without getting taken date application works fine. when I try to get date , application stops working , but it pass all lines, doesn't throw any exception

Comment: @Nininea You need to step line by line through the code and determine what line is causing the crash (or is the application just exiting normally?)

Comment: I know debugging, but it is not a simple case. without getting date from exit only modal is closed (as expected), but if I added this code , what I wrote all lines will be executes inside file upload method and  than application is terminated (it shouldn't be so )

Comment: I was working for me too, after update xamarin version it stopped working :(

Comment: Then just mock `takenDate` with a date in the line after `takenDate = DateTime.ParseE....` as a debugging test... and trace/debug it from there.

Comment: I have changed code :
using (var stream = File.Open (url.Path, FileMode.Open)) {
    var jpegInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg (stream);
    takenDate = DateTime.ParseExact (DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);
   }
it seems it works

Comment: I accept your answer, cause 
ExifLib.PCL Version: 1.0.2-pre01 is compatible .  for the main  problem , I had I wrote work around : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113284/get-image-taken-date-xamarin-mac