# Get image taken date xamarin mac

Tags: exif, cgimage, xamarin.mac

I need to get image taken date without exif extra libraries, what I found in documentations, doesn't work for me :

```
CGImageSource myImageSource;
        myImageSource = CGImageSource.FromUrl (url, null);
        var ns = new NSDictionary ();
        var imageProperties = myImageSource.CopyProperties (ns, 0);
    var date = imageProperties [ImageIO.CGImageProperties.ExifSubsecTimeOrginal];
    var date2 = imageProperties [ImageIO.CGImageProperties.ExifDateTimeDigitized];
    var date3 = imageProperties [ImageIO.CGImageProperties.TIFFDateTime];
```

all of them is null , but image has taken date, when I check it with exif library.

what is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my solution, not sure how perfect it is , but works for now

```
static DateTime GetMyImageTakenDate (NSUrl url)
        {
            DateTime takenDate = DateTime.Today;

            CGImageSource myImageSource;
            myImageSource = CGImageSource.FromUrl (url, null);
            var ns = new NSDictionary ();
            var imageProperties = myImageSource.CopyProperties (ns, 0);

            NSObject date = null;
            var exifDictionary = imageProperties.ValueForKey (ImageIO.CGImageProperties.ExifDictionary);
            if (exifDictionary != null) {
                date = exifDictionary.ValueForKey (ImageIO.CGImageProperties.ExifDateTimeOriginal);
            }
            takenDate = date != null ? DateTime.ParseExact (date.ToString (), "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null) : takenDate;
            return takenDate;
        }
```